# Curve Stroke Option in Draw tool does not appear in edit mode

Tags: sculpting, draw-mode

I am having difficulty replicating the modelling process for the Draw tool in edit mode as shown in this video at 58sec.

https://youtu.be/CjdH1CnX_yw?t=55

I am interested to get access to the "projection depth" and "surface" option so that I can apply my bezel curve to the cube. The draw tool is already selected in edit mode before I select "N".
Am I missing a step? I am using version 2.93.1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface has been reorganized a bit. I pretty sure that "Projection depth"  become just "Depth"